# How to add text to a .docx file using Apache POI in Java

Tags: java, apache-poi

I am new to Java and want to add data to an already existing .docx file and so far i've been unsucessful.
I've been looking for an answer to this for 3 days now and i decided to come to stackoverflow and ask how i could add text to an existing file using apache poi.

My program is supposed to generate a bunch of random data and store it in a file. Before Apache, i was using .write() to log my data and it was working well but the file didnt have formatting which was fine in the moment but now i need formatting to be able to get a good look at the thousands of data entries.

Here is the code i was using to log the data before:

```
FileWriter fwriteFinal = new FileWriter("obf_reg.docx", true);
fwriteFinal.write(lbrk);
fwriteFinal.write("\n");
fwriteFinal.write("Your Engine is called: " + engine_Name);
fwriteFinal.write("\n");
fwriteFinal.write("Your Engine Cycle is: " + nuclear_Cycle_Chosen + " " + engine_Cycle_Chosen);
fwriteFinal.write("\n");
fwriteFinal.write("Your Propellant is: " + propellant_List_Chosen);
fwriteFinal.write("\n");
fwriteFinal.write("Your Reactor's Fission Fuel is: " + reactor_Fuel_Chosen);
fwriteFinal.write("\n");
fwriteFinal.write("Your engine's nozzle type should be : " + nozzle_Type_List_Chosen);
fwriteFinal.write("\n");
fwriteFinal.write("Tank repressurisation would be done " + tank_Repressurisation_Chosen);
fwriteFinal.write("\n");
fwriteFinal.close();
```

and this is what im trying to use:

```
XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
XWPFParagraph par = docx.createParagraph();
XWPFRun run = par.createRun();
run.setText(lbrk + "\n" + "Your Engine is called: " + engine_Name + "\n" +
            "\n" + "Your Engine Cycle is: " + nuclear_Cycle_Chosen + " " + engine_Cycle_Chosen +
            "\n" + "Your Propellant is: " + propellant_List_Chosen +
            "\n" + "Your Reactor's Fission Fuel is: " + reactor_Fuel_Chosen +
            "\n" + "Your engine's nozzle type should be : " + nozzle_Type_List_Chosen +            
            "\n" + "Tank repressurisation would be done " + tank_Repressurisation_Chosen);
FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\sfsga\\OneDrive\\Desktop\\obf_reg.docx");
docx.write(out);
out.close();
```

its prolly a dumb mistake but im still gonna ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [*string literal*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5) `"\n"` does not have the usual special meaning in Microsoft Word. There are special settings for line breaks in Word.

You could use [XWPFRun.addBreak](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFRun.html#addBreak--) to add a line break into one text run. To do so each `"\n"` in your code would must be replaced by `run.addBreak()`.

Something like:

```
...
  run.setText(lbrk);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Engine is called: " + engine_Name);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Engine Cycle is: " + nuclear_Cycle_Chosen + " " + engine_Cycle_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Propellant is: " + propellant_List_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Reactor's Fission Fuel is: " + reactor_Fuel_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your engine's nozzle type should be : " + nozzle_Type_List_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Tank repressurisation would be done " + tank_Repressurisation_Chosen);
...
```

But more Word-lke is to use an additional paragraph for each time you would press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Word's GUI. Word also adds a new paragraph when the user press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Word's GUI.

Using different single `XWPFRun` per text run is also better for formatting later. All needed different text formatting needs their own `XWPFRun`.

If the need is to append data into the same file each time the code runs, then we need check whether the file already exists and, if so, create the `XWPFDocument` from that file. To do so constructor [public XWPFDocument(java.io.InputStream is)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#XWPFDocument-java.io.InputStream-) can be used.

That would look like follows in code:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;

import org.apache.poi.xwpf.usermodel.*;

public class CreateWord {

 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
     
  String lbrk = "Sample lbrk";
  String engine_Name = "Sample engine_Name";
  String nuclear_Cycle_Chosen = "Sample nuclear_Cycle_Chosen";
  String engine_Cycle_Chosen = "Sample engine_Cycle_Chosen";
  String propellant_List_Chosen = "Sample propellant_List_Chosen";
  String reactor_Fuel_Chosen = "Sample reactor_Fuel_Chosen";
  String nozzle_Type_List_Chosen = "Sample nozzle_Type_List_Chosen";
  String tank_Repressurisation_Chosen = "Sample tank_Repressurisation_Chosen";
  
  File file = new File("./obf_reg.docx");
  XWPFDocument docx = new XWPFDocument();
  if (file.exists()) {
   docx = new  XWPFDocument(new FileInputStream(file));
  } 

  XWPFParagraph par = docx.createParagraph();
  XWPFRun run = par.createRun();

/*
  run.setText(lbrk);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Engine is called: " + engine_Name);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Engine Cycle is: " + nuclear_Cycle_Chosen + " " + engine_Cycle_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Propellant is: " + propellant_List_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your Reactor's Fission Fuel is: " + reactor_Fuel_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Your engine's nozzle type should be : " + nozzle_Type_List_Chosen);
  run.addBreak();
  run.setText("Tank repressurisation would be done " + tank_Repressurisation_Chosen);

  par = docx.createParagraph();
*/

  par = docx.createParagraph(); run = par.createRun();
  run.setText(lbrk);
  par = docx.createParagraph(); run = par.createRun();
  run.setText("Your Engine is called: " + engine_Name);
  par = docx.createParagraph(); run = par.createRun();
  run.setText("Your Engine Cycle is: " + nuclear_Cycle_Chosen + " " + engine_Cycle_Chosen);
  par = docx.createParagraph(); run = par.createRun();
  run.setText("Your Propellant is: " + propellant_List_Chosen);
  par = docx.createParagraph(); run = par.createRun();
  run.setText("Your Reactor's Fission Fuel is: " + reactor_Fuel_Chosen);
  par = docx.createParagraph(); run = par.createRun();
  run.setText("Your engine's nozzle type should be : " + nozzle_Type_List_Chosen);
  par = docx.createParagraph(); run = par.createRun();
  run.setText("Tank repressurisation would be done " + tank_Repressurisation_Chosen);

  FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
  docx.write(out);
  out.close();
  docx.close();

 }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much for your advice!! do you know how i could stop it from replacing the previous text every time though?

Comment: Not clear what your problem is. The code creates a new **empty** `XWPFDocument` when it starts. So there is not any previous text. But there is [public XWPFDocument(java.io.InputStream is)](https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/dev/org/apache/poi/xwpf/usermodel/XWPFDocument.html#XWPFDocument-java.io.InputStream-) which is able to create a document from a given `InputStream`. That `InputStream` could come from a file having content already. Then the already stored content will stay present.

Comment: can you show me how to use it in the example?

Comment: @SpaceX Trooper: I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: This answer is better than any tutorial or reference I've seen.  I was confused about when to create a run, when to add paragraphs, and adding breaks and you cleared those topics right up!

Comment: I also didn't know that `XWPFRun.setText(String s)` _adds_ text to the run. The API says the method "Sets the text of this text run" which is incorrect.